# Multiple identity providers

Tags: authentication, jdbc, ldap, jwt, quarkus

here is my specifications

Some users of my application are employees of the company and must use the Active Directory to connect.

Others are external users who are referenced in the application database.

Once authenticated, the user receives a JWT token and it's this token which gives him access (RBAC) to the services of the application.

So I have to implement an authentication system that manages three methods, LDAP, JDBC, JWT.

How can we do that with quarkus ?

With Wildfly my authentication module tries to validate the login successively on a list of realms.

A simple solution seem be to use keycloak to aggregate different providers
But I'm asked preferably to have only one executable to deploy.
So I'm looking for a standalone solution.

Thank

Comment: Quarkus now supports combining multiple authentication mechanisms, please try combining the ldap, jdbc and either oidc or smallrye-jwt extensions and see how it goes, open an issue please if needed

Comment: Thank
The emergencies of the moment do not allow me to work on that. But I take note.
Bye

Comment: @SergeyBeryozkin could you provide more details how using multiple authentication mechanisms works? Where did you find this information? Are there somewhere samples out there?